# why git ignores my .data folder?

Tags: git

I have a .data folder: It seems ignored (no green mark) whereas I never added this folder to ignore list.

I looked in ignore I can't find anything either.

I even deleted .git and recreate a new repo same result.

Comment: `git add .data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git by default ignores all 'hidden' or `.folder` folders... that is any which begin with a `.`

This is because there is an inherent security risk with adding these accidentally as they often are used for storing private information.

As the comments pointed out, you can still manually add it using `git add .data`.